# messages from subfolders

Tags: ros, add-message-files, message, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm writing a Package, that has to contain multiple message definitions.
In order to manage the amount I divided the messages in subfolders:

> /msg/test 
> /msg/test2

I've already checked, this works(CMakeLists.txt):

> add_message_files(    FILES   
> test/test_msg.msg 
>  )

However: I still have to list every .msg in add_message_files. Is there a way to add whole folders? (Every .msg in a particular subfolder of /msg?

cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212420/messages-from-subfolders/) by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/genmsg/html/usermacros.html) for `genmsg` (where `add_message_files(..)` is coming from) and at the [code](https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/4eca6e3c3b38a26406862624d6d0ec149bf1e2b1/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake.em#L76-L135) (specifically: [here](https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/4eca6e3c3b38a26406862624d6d0ec149bf1e2b1/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake.em#L103-L111)) it would seem that if you only pass the `DIRECTORY` argument to `add_message_files(..)` it will search for `.msg` files in that directory. So that would remove the need to list all files explicitly.

I'm not sure whether it does that recursively though (most likely not, as `GLOB_RECURSE` is not used), so that would require calling `add_message_files(DIRECTORY ..)` multiple times (once for each subdir of `$pkg_dir/msg` in your specific case) and I don't know whether that is supported.

Note btw that this 'auto-discovery of `msg` files' uses `GLOB`-ing, which is sort-of frowned upon in the CMake community (see [Best way to specify sourcefiles in CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027247/best-way-to-specify-sourcefiles-in-cmake) on stackoverflow fi).

---

As an aside: making things explicit in software (engineering) is actually a good thing, as it avoids depending on implicit assumptions in your components (ie: "*message `my_message.msg` will be there, as it is in the directory I have catkin search for messages*"). If you `GLOB`, a missing msg file will cause an error at a much later time (while compiling any sources depending on the message) than if you explicitly listed it (existence of `.msg` files is checked at configuration time [here](https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/4eca6e3c3b38a26406862624d6d0ec149bf1e2b1/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake.em#L113-L116)) and it will also be more easily understood (ie: `message file not found` vs `some/path/to/my_source.cpp:LINE:CHAR: fatal error: my_msgs/my_msg.h: No such file or directory` which can also be caused by missing or misstated dependencies).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2